# Adding custom properties when uploading a file to Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to use the Google API Java Client Library to upload a file to Drive via an Android app.  I want to add a couple custom properties to the file when I upload it:

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle( localFile.getName() );
body.setDescription( "This is a test file made by Android Gro." );
body.setParents( Collections.singletonList( new ParentReference().setId( parentId ) ) );

ArrayList<Property> props = new ArrayList<>();
props.add( new Property().set( "GroFileType", "List" ).setVisibility( "PUBLIC" ) );
props.add( new Property().set( "GrotocolVersion", "0.1" ).setVisibility( "PUBLIC" ) );
body.setProperties( props );

client.files().insert( body, new FileContent( "text/plain", localFile )).execute();
```

If I *don't* add the properties (comment out the setProperties() line), everything is fine. However, if I do, I get the following exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The allowable values are letters, numbers, and the characters .!@$%^&*()-_/",
      "reason": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The allowable values are letters, numbers, and the characters .!@$%^&*()-_/"
}
```

Any idea what this means? Googling this exact exception message produces no results. I find it hard to believe that the problem is *really* with invalid characters in my properties, since I only use letters, numbers and a period.

Comment: That's not it -- the filename is "groTest1.txt", and as I mentioned, if I don't do the setProperties() call, the file is uploaded successfully.

Comment: I've found that adding these 2 properties as a separate call after inserting the file seems to work fine. So I guess the "answer" is to avoid File.setProperty() when uploading. Not satisfied with that (why does this call not work?) but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. What does not work is the Property.set(String,Object) call. However, if you use the two separate Property.setKey(String) and Property.setValue(String) calls, this error is not generated.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to take your word for it as I gave up on Drive properties and moved on to other methods.

Comment: @josh2112 as someone else struggling to use Drive as a platform, what other methods did you consider / use?